# Controlling for categorical variables before correlation using residuals?

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, residuals, continuous-data

I’m looking for a way to control for the effect of multiple categorical variables, all of which contain two independent categories, on two continuous variables before I correlate these continuous variables with each other. I’ve read about a way to do this by correlating residuals instead of the original data, however in the example that was used the control variable was continuous, so now I’m wondering if this can be done with multiple categorical control variables? And if it can, then what test would I use to produce the residuals?

Comment: Please discuss relation to the first thread you started.

Comment: Well, as I indicated in my first thread, I’m working on a research project in which I want to figure out a categorical variable’s effect on the strength of a correlation. In order to do this, first I need to control for the effects of a number of other categorical variables that are involved. I realized my first question might have been a little too broad so here I am with a more specific question about how to deal with my control variables.

Comment: It's good etiquette and good tactics at least to provide a cross-reference and explain all this. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115940/analyzing-the-effect-of-categorical-variables-on-a-correlation-coefficient

Comment: I'm sorry, yes it is, I'm still getting acquainted with the website. Thank you for keeping order.